# Error message when launching exe, with tkcalendar

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

```
from tkcalendar DateEntry

from tkinter import *
root=Tk()

root.title("Date picker")
d=DateEntry(root)
d.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

When I tried to open the executable file of this, there is an Error message when launching "[image]" my script name is dd
(I used Auto_py_to_exe to convert my python file)

Comment: You code has errors.So surely it could not run the exe file.

Comment: What are the errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the error and issue with your script.

1. You are not importing DateEntry

```
from tkcalendar import DateEntry

from tkinter import *
root=Tk()

root.title("Date picker")
d=DateEntry(root)
d.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

2. When you  are converting your script to exe you can see that there a module missing. If you want check the missing module then run this in your command prompt.

```
pyinstaller -F dd.py
```

It will show you that you have 'babel.numbers' module is missing.

Now coming to fixing this issue.
Use the below onliner to auto import the module and to convert your .py script to .exe.

```
pyinstaller.exe --hidden-import babel.numbers dd.py
```